# read keyboard/stdin asynchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, stdin

I have a loop where I would like to do something until a key is pressed.
Is there a way to read input from stdin in another thread until a specific key is pressed?
Is there a better way to do this?

```
def capture_loop(dev_path, breakout_key="a"):
    captured_devs = []
    capture = True

    def wait_for_key():
        global capture
        while True:
           i, o, e = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 10)
            if len(i) > 0:
            input_string = i[0].read()
                if breakout_key in str(input_string):
                    capture = False
                    break
            else:
                print("You said nothing!")

    t = threading.Thread(target=wait_for_key)
    t.setDaemon(False)
    t.start()

    while capture:
        print("Doing Stuff until the 'a' key is pressed")
        time.sleep(10)
    print("Done doing stuff")
```

Comment: Why do you want read input in another thread? Would check for `keypressed` and break on specific key be OK?

Comment: You could do this with a queue but it would necessitate looking into the queue for notification of the key press. If you are going to do that you may as well look for  keypressed instead, as AcK says above. That way you dispense with all the extra code.

Comment: The issue is that I've got a long running process that I want to run and exit gracefully from should a certain key be pressed. However, ctrl+c is already mapped to a function and does something different for the program.  I don't necessarily have to do it in another thread, but I do need to check if the key has at all been pressed at any time during the loop and not at the time the check is being performed. Unless there is a method to check and see if a character has ever been pressed, putting the check into a thread that constantly checks the keys seemed like the next logical step.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to do something until a key combination is pressed, but you don't care *what key combination* use, you can catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception which is raised when you press control-C:

```py
    try:
        while True:
            print("Doing something until C-c is pressed...")
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Done!")
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort. However, CTRL+C is already mapped to a very specific behavior that I would like to keep intact. Also, this isn't reading a character from stdin but rather receiving a signal and handling the signal.